# Routing to multiple apps in a LAN with domains.

Tags: domain-name-system, routing

I have a handful of apps running on a couple of boxes in a LAN.  All the apps use different ports.

For simplicity let's say I have two apps on one server, apache serving at 8080 and tomcat at 9292.  What I am trying to do is give each app a domain, say tomcat.local and apache.local.

I wave looked at bind but DNS a seems to only want to point to ip addresses.  I know load balancers have the capacity but I thought it may be overkill.  Is there a nice simple solution to set this up?

Answer (score 2):

You need in addition to dns entries, kind of proxy.

Example below show example of proxy based on apache used for jenkins:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName jenkins.localdomain

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    # ProxyPreserveHost On

    ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/jenkins_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/jenkins_access.log combined

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.100:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.100:8081/

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the suggestions already in here, is setting up multiple IP addresses on a single network interface.

For example, right now if you have `10.0.0.1` assigned to `eth0`. You can get the following setup without adding extra hardware:

```
eth0:0 10.0.0.1
eth0:1 10.0.0.2
eth0:2 10.0.0.3
eth0:n 10.0.0.n
```

Not sure of your OS, but [here is how it can be done in Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_One_Interface).

If you run [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) on the machine too (and use it as your name server for the other machines on the network)  then you can have in internal network and assign hostnames / virtual hosts to a unique IP address (this allows you to have apache running on `10.0.0.1:80` and tomcat on `10.0.0.1:80` and use e.g.: `apache.dev` and `tomcat.dev` to refer to the services locally)

This is the setup I use at work for our development servers (one box, gitlab and gitlabci and apache / php )

Comment: I have seen this done, but in general assigning more than one address to an interface is recipe for a mess. It can work for a while, but can get seriously mucked pun to the point nothing works as expected.

Comment: @JakeGould I have to disagree, IP aliasing is absolutely stable. This is (in my opinion) a cleaner solution than a reverse proxy (one less software/config to maintain, one less hop for request to travel through)

Comment: @faker So instead of a software config for Apache one needs to do network configs for an interface. Doesn’t seem like one is much harder than the other.

Comment: @JakeGould I'm not arguing which solution is harder to setup (both are trivial). In this case *I* would probably prefer IP aliasing. I do however argue that IP aliasing is a recipe for a mess or unstable in any way. It is widely used and I've never had or heard of problems with it.

Comment: @JakeGould network configs are much easier (3 lines each) and virtual IP assignments are extensively used. [ie when you buy a new pool of IP addresses to use for SSL certs they don't plug in new network cards for each ip address ]

Comment: @JakeGould I have never in my couple decades of mucking with computers ever heard anyone say that multiple IP addresses assigned to a NIC is in any way unstable or a "recipe for a mess." It's one of the most stable, most common, and least problematic things one can do with a network stack.

Answer (score 1):

> I know load balancers have the capacity but I thought it may be
>   overkill.

You want to use Apache reverse proxy coupled with Apache name-based virtual hosts. And for the record, load balancers basically use reverse parodying but with much more finessed logic in place help balance system traffic. The example I am going to outline is a fairly bare-bones version that works well for cases like this.

I am going to focus on the Tomcat service you have going through port `9292` for this example since it seems like port `8080` for Apache is a kludge you put in place to attempt to segment this? That’s not a judgement, but just an observation based on your examples. Irregardless, just read on for details on how I would tackle this.

First, be sure to enable the `proxy` and `proxy_http` modules in Apache like so. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 as an example:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http
```

And here is a quick example of how to setup a `tomcat.local` virtual host in Apache.  Note the `Proxy*` related items; that is the key to making it work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/tomcat.local/site/
  ServerName tomcat.local
  ServerAlias tomcat.local

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/tomcat.local.error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/tomcat.local.access.log combined

  # Settings for Confluence
  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>

    # Proxy specific settings
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
      AddDefaultCharset off
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9292/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9292/

  </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now restart Apache like so:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

So in this case, instead of going to `localhost:9292` you can go to `tomcat.local` and the proxy settings coupled with the virtual host settings will pipe `localhost:9292` to `tomcat.local`.

And typically when I do something like this I want to make sure all traffic to Tomcat goes through Apache, so I open up the Tomcat server XML file like so:

```
sudo nano /etc/tomcat6/server.xml
```

Look for the following settings:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"   
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

And then add `address="127.0.0.1` to restrict the connect to the `localhost` environment like so:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           address="127.0.0.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Now restart Tomcat like so:

```
sudo service tomcat6 restart
```

And at this point, Tomcat will be restricted to `localhost` but the Apache settings for name-based   virtual hosts & reverse prosing will pipe that traffic through `tomcat.local` exclusively.